# Creating a ActionLink that works with a javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have a datatable, on that datatable i set a Html.ActionLink. When I click that action link, I want to send an id of the item to a javascript function and have a new datatable appear below with all of its content that belongs to the selected item in the datatable above. So for example if I click a students name in a table, I want all the students Grades and Test to appear below in a separate datatable. I've never worked with javascript much so I'm not sure how I can do this. If someone can please point me in the right direction or give some tips I'd appreciate it.

original first datatable:

```
@foreach (var item in ((List<Epic>) ViewData["selectedestimate"]))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @*   @Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "action", "controller", new {id = item})*@

            <a href="#" onclick="StoryClick(@item.Id);">@item.Name</a>
        </td>
```

Javascript to call:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function StoryClick(story) {
    $.get("@Url.Action("action", "controller")", function (response) {
        $('#stories').accordion({ collapsible: true });
    });
}
</script>
```

ActionController:

```
public List<EpicDetails> getEpicDetails(int id)
{
    return eRepository.getItemsById(id).tolist();
}
```

Or do I need an ActionResult?

```
public Actionresult Details(int id)
{

}
```

I realize that I'm not even close right now, but its just b/c I'm not sure what steps to take to do this.
Eventually I would make a accordion and put the table in the accordion.

Comment: Hey if one of us helped you on your way you should give out upvotes and mark an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In situations like this I like to actually keep the `<a>` the `ActionLink` generates, and just add JavaScript to enhance the behavior of the link. So your view wouldn't really change (I did add a class so that we can bind an event handler to it later):

```
@Html.ActionLink(@item.Name, "action", "controller", new {id = item, @class = "item-link" })
```

Then write some jQuery (it looks like you already have a dependency on jQuery. If not, I can revise the answer to use vanilla JavaScript) to bind an event handler to links with class `item-link`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a.item-link").click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Stop the browser from redirecting as it normally would
            $.get(this.href, function (response) {
                // Do whatever you want with the data.
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

And, yes, your action method in the controller should return an `ActionResult`. It's hard for me to say what type of `ActionResult` you should return without actually knowing what type of data you want to consume on the client, but if you wanted to inject HTML onto the page, you could write something like this:

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var itemDetails = /* Get details about the item */;
    return PartialView("Details", itemDetails);
}
```

Then in your JavaScript you would write:

```
$("a.item-link").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Stop the browser from redirecting as it normally would
    $.get(this.href, function (response) {
        $("element_to_populate").html(response);
    });
});
```

Where `element_to_populate` would be a selector that points to where you want to inject the HTML.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When u set @class = "item-link", is that refering to the javascript u have above? And then when I make my new dattatable with the results how would I call/get the results to put into the table? I'm working with mostly strings and integers. Some how I would have to have a list returned of the object so that the datatable can just list them all by all their properties. Thx

Comment: `@class = 'item-link'` is just specifying a `class` attribute on the generated `a` tag. There *is* JS that binds events to links with that class though (in the `script` block). As for populating the table, you could serve up an entire view from the server and inject it into the page, or you could send down a JSON encoded list of items and write JavaScript to populate the table.

Comment: Don't forget to wrap the javascript in `$(function() { .... });` now that you're using jQuery so it runs when the document is ready

Comment: Wrap the javascript above with $(function() {}); ?

Comment: Sorry for all the need of help. A lot of this is over my head but I'm trying to learn it. So from here, what u have above, I would next need to configure my ActionResult in my controller, and somehow serve up a new view and inject it?

Comment: @TMan: Yeah that's a pretty good option, I'll update my answer to contain an example.

Comment: Ok cool well I'll give this a try. Is there any way, do you mind if I email you if I have any more questions later? Appreciate the help bro.

Comment: @TMan: Feel free to open up a chat with me or ask another question

Comment: Hey above u have return PartialView("Details", itemDetails) ..wouldn't itemDetails have to be an Int id since that is what Details takes in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9708/discussion-between-tman-and-andrew-whitaker)

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using javascript templating (I prefer [handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/)) on the client side and returning your student data as a JsonResult. This will keep your bandwidth usage to a minimum.

But, because you seem more comfortable with razor, you could use that for all your templates, return plain html from your controller/view, and then use this javascript instead

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("a.item-link").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // Stop the browser from redirecting as it normally would
        $("#gradesContainer").load(this.href, function (response) {
            //Do whatever you want, but load will already have filled up 
            //#gradesContainer with the html returned from your grades view
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

In your main page, below the student list, you would just need to add

```
<div id="gradesContainer"></div>
```

Your other controller would look like this

```
public ActionResult TestGrades(int id) {
    var model = getTestGradesModel(id);
    return View(model);
}
```

If you were returning JSON for client-side javascript templating it would look like

```
public ActionResult TestGrades(int id) {
    var model = getTestGradesModel(id);
    return new JsonResult() {Data = model}; //no view here!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, what do you mean when u say return plain html from my view though?

Comment: I should've said controller. I edited and added 2 example controllers.

Comment: now I wouldn't need to creat a view for the TestGrades Controller tho huh? The javascript would load it into the #gradesContainer?

Comment: There's two options there: 1) Create a view and make the html in razor, returning html (the view) from the controller. 2) returning JSON from the controller and using client-side javascript templating to render the testGrades data. Either way the javascript loads it, but the first option will be less work for you since you aren't familiar with javascript. I just wanted to plug for javascript templates because I love them :)

Comment: There's a lot of code missing to do javascript templating. If you wanted to go that route you'd have to read up a bit, play with it, and then ask more questions as necessary.

Comment: If I made a view making html in razor, would it be a partial view so that it can all be on the same page?

Comment: It only needs to be a partial if you want to render it as part of another view server side. Since you're making a completely separate request to the controller with javascript you could make it a full view: The controller won't know the difference between the javascript request and someone actually browsing to that specific URL in a web browser.

Comment: But really, it's your call. It doesn't matter, MVC won't care.

Comment: After more thought, I'd probably recommend returning a partial view, because that will give you more flexibility in the future. You could, for example, server-side render the very first grade item automatically with `@Html.RenderPartial(model.TestGrades.First())`

Comment: Yea I'm having a lot of trouble with this. Its going right over my head. It's frustrating lol. The Javascript above would be for the partial view or the view where I'll be injecting the partial view?

Comment: The javascript loads/injects the partial view when a user clicks on a link in your datatable. In order for the click event handler to bind the anchor tags need to be there. So the javascript should go in the main view the the grades would be injected to.

Comment: TO ensure you aren't having javascript errors, make sure you're using  a browser web developer toolkit. See http://www.browserstack.com/debugging-tools. You can press f12 in most browsers to get to them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9704/discussion-between-tman-and-scaryman)